# Edit Box Flexibility in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I kind of already know that the answer is most likely there is nothing that can be done, but I noticed that AnyLogic's edit boxes are very rigid in the sense that you cannot format the text alignment in them.

Is there a way to change the text alignment (aligned to the left instead of right)?
Is it also possible to have text wrapped instead of having it extend on one line only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do anything of what you say with the current edit box... You would have to create your own custom edit box.